# Laravel yajra datatable : Returning all integer value as string

Tags: php, laravel, datatable, laravel-5.8, yajra-datatable

Yajra laravel datatable returning all integer fields as a string value

currently i am using

name : yajra/laravel-datatables",
version: "v8.13.7",

[image]
below mentioned code is used in laravel side

$reportHeader = ReportHeader::with(['country'])->orderBy('reportSystemID',$sort);

```
return \DataTables::eloquent($reportHeader)
            ->order(function ($query) use ($input) {
                if (request()->has('order')) {
                    if ($input['order'][0]['column'] == 0) {
                        $query->orderBy('reportSystemID', $input['order'][0]['dir']);
                    }
                }
            })
            ->addIndexColumn()
            ->addColumn('reportStatus', function ($row) {
                return $this->getAlMahaReportStatus($row);
            })
            ->with('orderCondition', $sort)
            ->make(true);
```

Comment: Take a look at this issue, https://github.com/yajra/laravel-datatables/issues/1747 it is fixed in a PR for `8.13.12` version as it says. But then it was reverted again because of breaking changes :) so you should follow the progress on those issues :)

Comment: Okay i'll follow the progress @nakov

Answer (score 0):

For me the following solution worked in a laravel 5.5 project, although in this [conversation](https://github.com/yajra/laravel-datatables/issues/1747) [Pull Request](https://github.com/yajra/laravel-datatables/pull/2399)  it is solved if you can update to version 9.0 of the yajra package.

Add this in your return for all columns you don't want to escape, by default the package escape all columns to prevent XSS.

```
->rawColumns(['serialNo','companySystemID', ...])
```